# how to prevent aui-form from submission , when aui required filed validator is empty

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui

I have a form and a required field as shown below.
I added aui field validator for preventing form from submitting if the required field is empty.
But its not working.
Somebody please help me.

```html
<aui:form id="fm" name="fm" method="post" action="<%= someURL %>">
    <aui:input id="txtArea" label="value" name="preferences--txtArea--" type="textarea" style="width:330px;height:65px;" > 
        <aui:validator name="required" />
    </aui:input>
    <aui:input name="termsAndCondition" id="termsAndCondition" type="checkbox" label="termsAndConditons"/> <br>
    <aui:button type="button" value="save" onClick="showDialog()" />
</aui:form>

<aui:script>
function showDialog()
{
    var termsAndCondition= A.one('#<portlet:namespace/>termsAndCondition').attr('value');
    var r=confirm("Are you sure to change data?");
    if (r==true && termsAndCondition=="true")
    {
        A.one('#<portlet:namespace/>fm').submit();
    }
}
</aui:script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found mistake in my code..
I used button type = "button" as you can see

```
 <aui:button type="button" value="save" onClick="showDialog()" />
```

but for using aui field validator work according to requirement, to prevent from submitting the form when required field is empty. use button type="submit". so corrected line is

```
<aui:button type="submit" value="save" onClick="showDialog()" />
```

Now its working fine :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this approach

```
<aui:form id="fm" name="fm" method="post" action="<%= someURL %>" onSubmit="check();>


<script type="text/javascript">

  function check()
  {
  }
</script>
```

OR

you can **return false** from your **function showDialog()**

Hope this will help you

Comment: can you please tell me what to check in the function check() or in which condition return false from my function showDialog().

Comment: just keep check function as it is..and try it

Comment: does your controller going inside if when your "termsAndCondition" is false

Comment: one more thing is "if (r==true && termsAndCondition=="true")" you checking true differently..

Comment: "if (r==true && termsAndCondition=="true")"  its working fine as per requirement. form get submitted only if the checkbox is checked and got true value from the dialog box

Comment: I am not getting why the form is getting submitted when I am using aui field validator
<aui:input id="txtArea" label="value" name="preferences--txtArea--" type="textarea" style="width:330px;height:65px;" > 
    <aui:validator name="required" />
    </aui:input>

Comment: you can check checkbox is checked or not using "$('#termsAndCondition').is(':checked');"